# How to retrieve User.IsPortalEnabled info from CreatedBy field on a object like Feed Item using Apex and SOQL in Salesforce

Tags: apex, soql, query

I have used this query using `TYPEOF` operator in SOQL which returns me records in Workbench, but not sure how to retrieve values in actual apex code as it keeps on giving error. [image]

This is the query: `SELECT Id, TYPEOF CreatedBy WHEN User THEN CreatedBy.Name,createdby.isportalenabled END FROM FeedItem`

I want to fetch the `name` and `isportalenabled` property from `user` who created the `Feeditem`

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Community!!. Please edit your question and add the error details like error snapshot and debug results. So that community users are can able to understood the error easily and able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

To do this in Apex, you will need two queries, as `TYPEOF` queries only have limited support.

You can do:

```
List<FeedItem> feedItems = [SELECT Id, CreatedById FROM FeedItem WHERE CreatedBy.Type = 'User'];
```

Then put the user Ids in a list and do the following query:

```
List<Id> userIds = new List<Id>();
for(FeedItem fi : feedItems){
    userIds.add(fi.CreatedById);
}

List<User> users = [SELECT Id, IsPortalEnabled FROM User WHERE Id IN :userIds];
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for polymorphic queries doesn't require the relationship name

You have:

```
SELECT Id, TYPEOF CreatedBy WHEN User THEN Created.Name, Created.IsPortalEnabled END 
      FROM FeedItem
```

You can use:

```
SELECT Id, TYPEOF CreatedBy WHEN User THEN Name, IsPortalEnabled END 
      FROM FeedItem
```

To execute in Apex:

```
for (FeedItem feedItem: [SELECT Id, TYPEOF CreatedBy WHEN User THEN Name, IsPortalEnabled END 
                       FROM FeedItem]) {
   User user = (User) feedItem.CreatedBy;
   system.debug(user.Name + ' IsPortalEnabled=' +user.IsPortalEnabled);
}
```

Note you have to cast to `User` to get the polymorphic relationship object. If using more than one polymorphic object in the query, use `instanceOf` operator on `createdBy` to decide what object to cast to.